# com.codename1.util.regex.RESyntaxException - Syntax error: Mismatched class

Tags: codenameone

I tried to use regex to validate email using the code below:

```
RE pattern = new RE("^([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~]|-|_)+@((\\\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\\\-0-9]+\\\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$");
                    if(pattern.match(cont.getText()) == false)
                    {
                        getErrorLabel(tabIndex).setText("You have provided an invalid email.");
                        x = false;
                        error.repaint();
                    }
```

I get a runtime exception saying  `Exception: com.codename1.util.regex.RESyntaxException - Syntax error: Mismatched class`

I have also tried using TextComponent instead of TextField, same result.

What could be wrong?

Comment: This is an exception from the regular expression itself that indicates that a part of the expression isn't supported. Since this RE is pretty big and I suck at RE it's pretty hard for me to tell which part. I suggest going through the process of elimination to find the part that's at fault